# How to check that there are no other characters in the string except letters and whitespace

Tags: javascript

```
function getAbbreviation(str) {
}
console.log(getAbbreviation('some1 company name'))
```

How to check that there are no other characters in the string except letters and whitespace

Comment: I would suggest putting some code inside the function. Also take the [tour] and read [ask] - this isn't a code-writing or tutorial service.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression, You can use `^` to try to find any character that isn't `[a-z]` with `i` the case insensitive flag which means any English letter if capital or small, and `\s` means white space.

So, the regular expression will `test` the `string`, if there are any character that isn't an English letter or a white space.

```js
function getAbbreviation(str) {
  return !/[^a-z\s]/i.test(str)
}
console.log(getAbbreviation('some company name'))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use string replace to remove the special characters using regex (except letters and whitespace)

```
function getAbbreviation(str) {
  return str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "");
}
```

Comment: Whitespace can be tabs or new lines. Use \s or \S

Comment: Please also tell what you are doing here and point to documentation. Besides that, this regex will not get all white space, only normal spaces.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).